# Как реализовать Telegram bot в несколько файлов?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Всех приветствую, делаю Telegram Bot'а на Python с библиотекой telebot.
Код постепенно становится длинным и не особо удобным.
Поставил для себя задачу разделить его на несколько модулей.

Есть главный файл main.py и побочный cycle.py.
В главном файле лежит /start с вызовом нескольких Reply кнопок. Каждая кнопка предполагает после нажатия запуск определенного процесса (пока сделан только один процесс и лежит в cycle.py)
По отдельности все работает, но не знаю как это все совместить (недостаточно знаний в программировании).

В связи с этим вопросы:

1. Как или через что реализовать переход с нажатия Reply кнопки на запуск небольшого опросника в Cycle.py и последующем возвращением в меню в Main.py?
2. Более простой и побочный вопрос, но все равно еще до конца с этим не разобрался. Как реализовать config.py в котором будет лежать токен, пароль и словарь с фразами для ответов?
   Огромная просьба, если кого-то заинтересует мой вопрос, можно более подробный ответ на 1 пункт. Что куда импортировать? Как обратиться к блоку? Какие нужны в конце основного и побочного файла функции, чтобы бот работал? Имею в виду :
   `bot.polling(none_stop=True)`
   или
   `if __name__=='__main__':  bot.polling(none_stop=True)`
   или

bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)

bot.load_next_step_handlers()

if **name**=='**main**':
bot.polling(none_stop=True)

p.s. Если это важно, в main.py есть SQLite для добавления пользователей, а в cycle.py есть Class для сбора данных опросника и дальнейшего занесения (в этой же функции) в таблицу SQLite.

Буду рад любому ответу или примеру)

Пример кода main.py:

```
    import telebot
    from telebot import types
    import sqlite3
    
    
    bot = telebot.TeleBot("<Token>") 
    
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def menu_step(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
        markup.add('Анкета 1', 'Анкета 2')
        markup.add('Обратная связь')
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери ниже', reply_markup=markup)

        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Пример кода Cycle.py

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot("<Token>") 

user_data = {}

class User:
    def __init__(self, datas):
        self.datas = datas
        self.datass = ''

conn = sqlite3.connect('DataBase.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()

def db_table_val(user_id: int, dataone: str, datatwo: str):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO datatable (user_id, dataone, datatwo) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (user_id, dataone, datatwo))
    conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['anketaone'])
def send_welcome(message):
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите данные №1")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_one_step)

def process_one_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user_data[user_id] = User(message.text)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите данные №2')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_two_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка')

def process_two_step(message):
    try:
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_data[user_id]
        user_data[user_id] = User(message.text)
        db_table_val(user_id=user_id, dataone=user.datas, datatwo=user.datass)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно ввели все данные')
    except Exception as e:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка')

bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)

bot.load_next_step_handlers()

if __name__=='__main__': 
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**
C Config все вышло достаточно просто.
А вызывать def из другого файла через bot.register_next_step_handler у меня не получается. Код запускается без ошибок, но бот перестает отвечать и пока не удалю **pycache** и блок с перенаправлением на другой файл ничего не работает.

**Что я делал?**

1. Импортировал побочный файл в главный через import
2. Дописал часть кода

   ```
    def statistics_step(message):
        if message.text.lower() == 'анкета 1: #т.к. нижний регистр
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Анкета')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, cycle.send_welcome)
   ```
3. В конце кода Cycle.py оставил     bot.polling()
4. А в главном в конце написал:

   ```
    if __name__=='__main__': 
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
   ```
5. Попробовал разные варианты с концовкой кода, но все никак (

p.s. если убрать bot.polling(none_stop=True) или просто bot.polling() в побочном файле, все запускается, но цикл в нём не работает соответственно.

Comment: приведите пример кода из `main.py` и `cycle.py`

Comment: @Violet
Добавил в текст вопроса примерную логику бота по вашей просьбе.
Хочется, чтобы при нажатии на клавиатуре "Анкета 1" в начальном меню из main.py вызывался весь процесс из Cycle.py и по завершению либо автоматический возвращался в меню, либо пользователь выбирал.
Предполагаю, что это делается как то через  bot.register_next_step_handler, но что для этого еще нужно поправить в конце и начале кода еще не разобрался.

Comment: Участник @Роман просил "уточните, удалось ли решить вопрос №1. Не могу найти информации по вопросу, столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Буду признателен за любую информацию"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу импорта config.py всё просто:

1. Создаёте в корне проекта config.py
2. В config.py укажите переменную и присвойте ей ваш токен - `token = "ваш токен"`
3. В main.py в начале прописываете `import config`
4. В main.py обратитесь к вашему токену - `bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)`

Что насчёт первого вопроса, то можете попробовать так же.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось)

Comment: рад что у вас вышло)