# Как сделать оповещение в Telegram bot'е?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, время, telebot

Всех приветствую! Мне нужно сделать таймер в Telegram бот'е, который раз в три дня напоминает в групповой чат о необходимости заняться ремонтом.

Пользователь вызывает команду /remont (условно) -> Отвечает на вопрос "Что именно?" -> Отвечает на вопрос "Какая неисправность?". Далее это все заносится в базу данных SQLite в строки: user_id, what_broke, defect, date_of_detection.

date_of_detection получаю таким образом:

```
tconv = lambda x: time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d.%m.%Y", time.localtime(x))
date = tconv(message.date)
```

В таблицу все выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### **Что я пытался?**

Пробую это сделать через отдельный цикл, который раз в трое суток включается и проверяет дату, застрял на проверке в БД, не могу нормально сравнить с датой в базе, выдаёт очень странные значения.
def select_yesterday_tasks(cursor):
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT (*) FROM remont WHERE date_of_detection < date('now','-3 day')")
for row in rows:
bot.send_message(group_id, row)

В случае с вышеуказанной таблицей, выдаёт по очереди 4 сообщения 1,2,3,4. Хотя указанные даты не соответствуют условию -3 дня от 'now' (предполагаю что БД считает от своей даты занесения в таблицу, но тогда тоже не соответствует условию)

Хотелось бы, чтобы выдача была : что именно сломано и соответствует условию (- 3 day).

Буду рад любому примеру, варианту решения моей проблемы или другому плану реализации, а то совсем запутался.

P.S. TelegramBotAPI+Python+SQLite

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вести счетчик времени от даты в таблице? PytelegramBotApi, Python, SQLite](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347816/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-pytelegrambotapi-python-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, моё решение можно сравнить с костылём, вернее это даже так и есть. Но можете попробовать хранить дату строкой, во вторых, не совсем понял зачем Вам ещё один цикл, если есть цикл `который раз в трое суток включается`. Значит это время прошло, и вы можете отправлять, либо же если Вы хотите работать с множеством сообществ, то вы уже делаете цикл(запускающийся например раз в минуту) и уже там пробегаетесь по базе данных и смотрите где время прошло. Также вы можете, при запуске программы ввести некий счетчик(секунд к примеру). И при получение сообщение в бд, вводить этот счетчик(только не используйте обычный int). И уже при обходе базы данных проверять разницу нынешнего счетчика и записи в бд. Но несмотря на то, что этот метод проще, не рекомендую так делать, потому что сервер может отпасть и время собъётся